# How to add a health check in .NET 5 for MassTransit Amazon SQS?

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit, .net-5, health-check

I have a working and running .NET 5 application. There is a REST API to POST data. When data is posted, a MassTransit message is published. Using the [AWS Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017), I can clearly see that if the topic named *customerinfo.fifo* does not exist, it is created in Amazon by my application. Apparently, my application does something useful with Amazon SQS/SNS. I like that.

What I do not like, is that when adding a health check, an error appears causing my health check to be "Unhealthy" (after calling http://localhost:5000/health/ready ). This should not happen as my application is working fine and being able to publish messages. Logically, an "Unhealthy" status should only occur when there is something wrong. Here is my code responsible for the health check. This is part of the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            options.Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready");
        });
```

To use the added health check, the following code is added to the `Configure` method.

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/ready", new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready"),
            });

            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions());
        });
```

This code shown above is basically how it is documented in the [MassTransit documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core). Moreover, I also have code to add [MassTransit SQS](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/amazonsqs.html) itself.  I have specific extension method for this:

```
    public static void UseMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, MassTransitConfiguration massTransitConfiguration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>();
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(massTransitConfiguration.Host, h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey(massTransitConfiguration.AccessKey);
                    h.SecretKey(massTransitConfiguration.SecretKey);
                    h.EnableScopedTopics();
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("CustomerChangeConsumer",
                    configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.ConfigureConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>(context);
                    });

                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate.fifo");
                });

                cfg.Publish<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.TopicAttributes["FifoTopic"] = "true";
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
```

To solve this problem, two solution types are possible:

1. Just remove the MassTransit health check. It cannot fail it is not there any more.I need to find a way to implement a SQS/SNS health check myself when choosing such a solution.
2. Fix (my?) code in order to make the health check work properly.

Obviously, the last one is preferred but for both solution types, I have no idea how to implement them.

To further clarify my problem, the logged error message when doing a health check is shown here.

> fail:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.DefaultHealthCheckService[103]
> Health check masstransit-bus completed after 13.2985ms with status Unhealthy and description 'Not ready: not started'
> MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Exceptions.AmazonSqsConnectionException:
> ReceiveTransport faulted: https://eu-west-2/
> ---> Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ is denied.
> ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException'
> was thrown.
> at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeValueFactory`1.CreateValue()
> at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeTracker`1.AddNode(INodeValueFactory`1
> nodeValueFactory)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveTransport`1.ReceiveTransportAgent.RunTransport() at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveTransport`1.ReceiveTransportAgent.Run()

I really hope there someone can help me with this. It is so strange. MassTransit and SQS/SNS are working fine together. The only problem is that the health check denies that, which is really frustrating.

[image]

Comment: have you find any solution I am getting the same error `Health check masstransit-bus completed after 0.0497ms with status Unhealthy and 'Not ready: not started'` I am using asp.net 3.1 with masstransit (sns/sqs)

Comment: @NirajTrivedi No, for now I just do not use the health check.

Comment: few places i found that we need to implement custom health check with ping pong command

Answer (score 0):

I found some link where they say you need to define the custom health check like below

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1513#issuecomment-554943164

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `Autostart = true`? It helped me with RabbitMq so possibly it will help you as well.

```
mt.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {                    
                cfg.Host(massTransitConfiguration.Host, h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey(massTransitConfiguration.AccessKey);
                    h.SecretKey(massTransitConfiguration.SecretKey);
                    h.EnableScopedTopics();
                });

                cfg.AutoStart = true;

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("CustomerChangeConsumer",
                    configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.ConfigureConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>(context);
                    });

                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate.fifo");
                });

                cfg.Publish<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.TopicAttributes["FifoTopic"] = "true";
                });
            });
```

Comment: This solved my problem as well ... Do you know why this helps? I cant read it in the docs.

Comment: My understanding is that your bus don't know if message broker is working or not until you start using it but on application startup you are not using bus right away so health check is showing that bus is not working. In case when k8s is checking health checks once it see that this is failing it restarts the app again and again... 
Some info about `AutoStart` can be found here https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2159